# Как сбросить Биос, если в настройках Биоса отключил монитор

Tags: железо, bios, пк

Есть pos моноблок, в Биоса зачем то выключил наверно видеокарту, теперь ничего не показывает, есть ли способ сбросить би

Comment: Надо смотреть доки либо на материнку, либо от производителя биоса (если помните чей биос). Бывает сочетание клавиш для сброса в начальные настройки. Либо бывает волшебный тумблер на материнке. Либо запасная микросхема с биосом. Всяко бывает, надо читать доки.

Comment: А вслепую Биос нельзя сбросить?

Answer (score 1):

Если это моноблок и нет возможности подключить дополнительный монитор (раз уж видеокарта отключена), то сбросить настройки bios можно аппаратно

> выключите и переверните его тыльной стороной вверх. Возможно, вы увидите небольшое отверстие с надписью CMOS. Вам необходимо вставить в него острый предмет, например, скрепку, и подержать его около 30 секунд.
>
> Если такого отверстия в моноблоке нет, его придется разобрать. Иногда
> бывает достаточно просто снять нижнюю крышку. Для сброса БИОС
> необходимо на 30-40 минут извлечь батарейку, питающую CMOS-память. Она
> расположена на материнской плате, чаще всего недалеко от слотов PCI, и
> обычно легко доступна. В очень старых моделях батарейка может
> оказаться припаянной, ее придется заменить. Вставьте источник питания
> на место, соберите ноутбук и включите его. Вам придется зайти в БИОС,
> чтобы установить время, дату и выбрать порядок загрузки.

либо таким образом:

> выключите компьютер, отсоедините кабель питания, откройте корпус системного блока и найдите на материнской плате перемычку с названием CLRTC, CLR_CMOS, CLEAR_CMOS, CLRRTC.
> Переставьте перемычку из положения 1-2 в положение 2-3 приблизительно на 5-10 секунд, затем верните перемычку в положение 1-2

Comment: Вслепую нельзя биос сбросить

Comment: что значит вслепую? мой вариант подразумевает замыкание контактов с открытыми глазами :)

Comment: Всмысле когда экран не показывает, но попробовать зайти в Биос без дисплея

Comment: без дисплея можно зайти в биос - нужна только клавиатура. посмотрите на ютубе как устроено меню вашего биоса (либо если у вас есть второй такой же моноблок) и вслепую повторите действия. вы предполагаете, что отключена видеокарта и проблема только в bios, однако, есть вероятность, что проблема не только в bios - нужно рассматривать все возможные проблемы.